# How to dynamically receive udp message from the source port using netty?

Tags: java, netty

I need to communicate with a server using udp message like this. For example, my client ip is 192.168.86.50 and the server is listening to port 7777 on address 127.0.0.1

UDP message from my client to server: 192.168.86.50:54321 --> 127.0.0.1:7777

The client will reply with a UDP message like this: 127.0.0.1:7777 --> 192.168.86.50:54321

How do I write Netty to dynamically listening to a source port of a udp message? The source port is dynamically generate from the OS.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the Source (local) address while connecting.

Here is a snippet:

```java
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
        .group(new NioEventLoopGroup(1))
        .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
        .handler(new Handler());

SocketAddress serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 7777);
SocketAddress localAddress = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.86.50", 5555);

bootstrap.connect(serverAddress, localAddress);
```